# Converting a string date to a date when using a SortDescription

Tags: wpf, date, sorting

My WPF app using an `XMLDataProvider` for its data. The XML file has a

```xml
<RELEASEDATE>dd/mm/yyyy</RELEASEDATE>
```

for each of the listed items. I'm sorting the data in the app using a

```cs
Listbox1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("RELEASEDATE", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

The results aren't what expected as the date is treated as a string.

What is the most elegant way around this? Can I somehow convert to a date inline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement own IComparer:

```
class DateTimeComparer : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            //To Do : Implement DataTime Comparering
        }
    }
```

and now assign the IComparer implementation to the  collection's ListCollectionView.CustomSort:

```
 ListCollectionView view = new ListCollectionView(ListBox.Items);

 view.CustomSort = new DateTimeComparer();
```

[See similar Question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/44efe318-0246-4021-a193-8a20b95ae55e)

Comment: Thank you, I'm implementing this asap!