# wpf listview Sorting Dates

Tags: wpf, sorting, listview

I'm using this to sort a list view: [ListView with column sorting](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-how-to-column-sorting/). It's working great, except when I try to sort a date column

```
21/11/2015 10:00:00 
23/11/2015 20:22:51
```

So how can I sort?

Comment: Does the column actually contain a DateTime object or the text representation of the date?

Comment: Question goes in the same direction as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157306/converting-a-string-date-to-a-date-when-using-a-sortdescription

Comment: # ChrisF  - Column contain a text representation of the date

Answer (score 0):

If the column contains a `DateTime` object then the sorting should "just work" as the sorting of dates is solved.

However, if the column contains the text representation of the date then the sorting won't work how you expect as the date time is being treated as a string which obeys different rules.

You either need to put a `DateTime` object in the column and use a formatter to get the data out in the format you require, display in a string format that allows for the correct sorting or [create a custom comparer for your preferred date/time output string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157306/converting-a-string-date-to-a-date-when-using-a-sortdescription).

Comment: Formatting can be used like this: "{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" />